# Buttons are two pixels too small

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have been working with windows forms for a short while and have noticed that button controls always appear one pixels smaller in each direction than I am trying to make them.

To illustrate, the `TextBoxes` and `Button` in the image bellow are set to the exact same size but are different sizes.

[wrong size buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa6q5.png)
Here is the code that I used to generate the buttons:

```
public Form1() {

    InitializeComponent();

    this.Size = new Size(216, 239)

    TB1 = new TextBox();
    TB1.Multiline = true;
    TB1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
    TB1.Location = new Point(100, 0);
    Controls.Add(TB1);

    TB2 = new TextBox();
    TB2.Multiline = true;
    TB2.Size = new Size(100, 100);
    TB2.Location = new Point(0, 100);
    Controls.Add(TB2);

    TestButton = new Button();
    TestButton.Text = "sdfsdf";
    TestButton.Size = new Size(100, 100);
    TestButton.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    Controls.Add(TestButton);

}
```

From the Image you can see that there is white space around the button. I have tried changing the `Control.Margin` and `Control.Padding` but this extra space around the button is unaffected by those.

In order to make the button appear 100x100 (the way I want it) you have to move it one pixel up and to the left and make it two pixels wider and taller. (`TextButton.Size = new Size(102, 102); TextButton.Location = new Point(99, 99);`)

What I would like to do is make the buttons actually the size I set them to be. Because of the number of buttons in my program, it is undesirable to manually increase the size of each button and I am looking for a more elegant long term solution that I can use going forwards.

I have tried to create a wrapper class around the button class called MyButton but it doesn't work with polymorphism (explained bellow):

```
class MyButton : Button {

    public MyButton() : base() {}

    public new Size Size {

        get;
        set {
            int width = value.Width + 2; // make it two wider
            int height = value.Height + 2; // make it two taller
            Size size = new Size(width, height);
            base.Size = size;
        }
    }

    public new Point Location {

        get;
        set {
            Console.WriteLine("running"); // used to make sure this is actually being run
            int x = value.X - 1; // move it one left
            int y = value.Y - 1; // move it one up
            Point point = new Point(x, y);
            base.Location = point;
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a MyButton object and use `myButtonObject.Size = ...` it works perfectly and the button sizing and location works out. However, at another place in my code I have a function that takes a `Control` object as input and here my code from the `MyButton` class is not being used.

```
MyButton btn1 = new MyButton();
btn1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
btn.Location = new Point(100, 100);
// ^ this works great and the button is the right size

public void ControlFormatter(Control control) {
    control.Size = new Size(100, 100);
    control.Location = new Point(100, 100);
}

MyButton btn2 = new MyButton();
ControlFormatter(btn2);
// ^ this doesn't work
```

Using the `Console.WriteLine("running")` print statement that I put in `MyButton.Location.Set`, I can tell that when `control.Location` is called inside `ControlFormatter()` the code that I wrote is not run (I can only assume that it is using the default `Control.Location` property and thus making the buttons the wrong size.

I guess I'm asking two things

1. Is there an easier/better/cleaner way to make the buttons the right size?
2. How can I make it so that `ControlFormatter()` uses `MyButton.Size` when it can and not `Control.Size`?

Thanks, also I'm fairly new to C# so grace is appreciated.

Comment: You're not calculating the Focus rectangle that is drawn around some Controls, as the Button control. The TextBox control doesn't have a Focus rectangle drawn around its internal edges. I suggest to add your controls to a TableLayoutPanel instead of trying to position them *manually*. You can use the child controls `Margin` and the Container's `Padding` properties to space them smoothly.

Comment: @Jimi The focus rectangle for a button is drawn within its borders, not around the control per se. I think the 2 pixel difference the OP described is actually due to Visual Styles. If you disable Visual Styles and allow the controls to render in classic Win32 style, the extra spacing disappears.

Comment: @Bradley Smith The borders that you see and the actual borders are two different things. Of course the Focus rectangle is drawn inside the bounds of the control; what you see, when the Button is not selected, is the internal border. It's more visible if you set `Button.FlatStyle = Flat` and you move the focus in/out of the Button. The normal border is transparent (same color as the Parent's). You can modify it with `ControlPaint.DrawBorder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for the quicker and dirtier fix of testing whether or not the Control was a Button in my ControlFormatter() function.

```
public void ControlFormatter(Control control) {
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;

    if (control is Button) {
        width -= 2;
        height -= 2;
    }

    control.Size = new Size(width, height);
    control.Position = new Point(); // you get the jist
}
```